# How to pack model queryset in serializer into one field DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

For example i have a few models:

```
class Parent(Model):
   api_key = CharField(max_length=250)

class Child(Model):
   parent = ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
   status = CharField(max_length=250)
```

I wrote view based on ListAPIView, and serializer:

```
class ChildSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       fields = ['id']
```

I need to take all Children with parent by find Parent by api_key and return this as:

```
{
  children:[
   {'id':1},
   {'id':2}
]}
```

But i take this:

```
[
{'id':1},
{'id':2}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can define a `ParentSerializer` which will also return the child objects data with it:

```
class ParentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    child = ChildSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
       fields = ['api_key', 'child']
```

Then you need to find the parent by `api_key` and pass the `Parent` object to this `serializer`. Like this:

```
class ParentView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Parent.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'api_key'
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'api_key'
```

Finally set the `url` to:

```
path('/parent/<str:api_key>/', ParentView.as_view(), name='parent-detail')
```

### Update

If you need to get the data from `request.GET`(url querystring), then it much simpler. Try like this:

```
class ParentView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Parent.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        api_key = request.GET.get('api_key')
        if api_key:
           return queryset.filter(api_key=api_key)
        return queryset
```

Comment: I need to take api_key from GET request

Comment: Does it have more generic way? i mean without overriding get method? also thanks